# How to imitate a character that looks similar to an inverted 2?

Tags: symbols, text-mode

I am trying to imitate a character that looks similar to an inverted 2. It can be seen at the start of the second last words in the following image:

[image: sample with character similar to inverted 2]

What I have come up with so far is using `graphicx`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx,tipa}
\begin{document}
Si m"ue"sti d t"a\textesh\textesh{}en uf \scalebox{1}[-1]{2}tans \textesh{}icke

\emph{Si m"ue"sti d t"a\textesh\textesh{}en uf \scalebox{1}[-1]{2}tans \textesh{}icke}
\end{document}
```

However, this is not quite right. It inverts the character, but it is placed way too low:

[image: inverted 2 positioned way too low]

Is there a better way for inverting the character than using `graphicx`?

If I use `graphicx` how do I get the character back on the line?

Comment: You could use `\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{2}` instead of `\scalebox`. But a font that has this special character (What kind of S is that? Is it in Unicode?) would be better. Should `\textesh` be a long s (= „ſ“)?

Comment: How is this symbol called?

Comment: Forgot to explain: It is a suggestion for an uppercase esh (not the long ſ) in Eugen Dieth (1936): _Schwyzertütschi Dialäktschrift_ [Swiss German dialect spelling]. It has never caught on, so there is no Unicode character. I wish to cite it, though.

Comment: The uppercase Esh is in Unicode but it does look more like a Sigma: Ʃ I guess you really have to create it on your own.

Comment: LATIN CAPITAL LETTER ESH has the comment “African” in the Unicode Standard, and it is intended for orthographies of some African languages. In all fonts that support it, it seems to be very much like capital sigma. So it’s really not appropriate here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The upright form can easily be based from the “2”.
The italic one is a bit tricky.

I don't think you can avoid creating your own character here or putting more graphical effort in it.

If you had that glyph in some kind of digital form you could include it in your document (License!).

### Code

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx,tipa}
\newcommand*\Esh{\scalebox{-1}[1]{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{2}}}
\newcommand*\Eshit{\raisebox{1.75ex}{\kern-.15em\rotatebox{-20}{\scalebox{1}[-1]{2}}}\kern-.1em}
\begin{document}
Si m"ue"sti d t"a\textesh\textesh en uf \Esh tans \textesh icke \par
\emph{Si m"ue"sti d t"a\textesh\textesh en uf \Eshit tans \textesh icke} \par
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image: Output]

### `"h`, `"H` and `"Y`

You can declare further short hands for other characters, too

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx,tipa}
\newcommand*\Esh{\scalebox{-1}[1]{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{2}}}
\newcommand*\Eshit{\raisebox{1.75ex}{\kern-.15em\rotatebox{-20}{\scalebox{1}[-1]{2}}}\kern-.1em}
\makeatletter
\declare@shorthand{ngerman}{"h}{\textormath{\textesh}{?esh?}}
\declare@shorthand{ngerman}{"H}{\textormath{\Esh}{?Esh?}}
\declare@shorthand{ngerman}{"Y}{\textormath{\Eshit}{?Esh?}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Si m"ue"sti d t"a"h"hen uf "Htans "hicke \par
\emph{Si m"ue"sti d t"a"h"hen uf "Ytans "hicke} \par
\end{document}
```

### `inputenc`, `utf8` and `newunicodechar`

Make sure your TeX editor saves in UTF8.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\usepackage{graphicx,tipa}
\newcommand*\Esh{\scalebox{-1}[1]{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{2}}}
\newcommand*\Eshit{\raisebox{1.75ex}{\kern-.15em\rotatebox{-20}{\scalebox{1}[-1]{2}}}\kern-.1em}
\makeatletter
\declare@shorthand{ngerman}{"h}{\textormath{\textesh}{?esh?}} % still work
\declare@shorthand{ngerman}{"H}{\textormath{\Esh}{?Esh?}}     % still work
\declare@shorthand{ngerman}{"Y}{\textormath{\Eshit}{?Esh?}}   % still work
\makeatother
\newunicodechar{ʃ}{\textesh}
\newunicodechar{Ʃ}{\Esh}
\begin{document}
Si müeßti d täʃʃen uf Ʃtans ʃicke \par
\emph{Si müeßti d täʃʃen uf "Ytans ʃicke} \par
"h"H\textit{"Y}
\end{document}
```

### XeTeX, LuaLaTeX

If you often find yourself writing text with many “special” characters outside of `a-zA-ZäöüÄÖÜß` take a look at XeTeX and LuaLaTeX.

They offer default UTF8 input and easier Unicode support. (This still doesn't help you if you can't find a font that has your special Esh.)

Comment: You could certainly skew the italic "2" in the other direction (instead of rotating it against its skewing) with a TikZ transformation …

Comment: Thank you very much for these suggestions! I think this is as good as it gets without drawing a new character (for improved line width etc.). Since I only need citing the character once, this is what I am going for. If I were to draw the character, I would certainly encode it as a variant of ‹Ʃ› (Unicode's uppercase ‹ʃ›). It is nice to see that even an italic inverted ‹2› can be faked.